# How do I allow Chrome Android to load "insecure" or "phishing" content?

Tags: chrome-for-android

How do I allow Chrome for Android to load insecure content?  I would like to know this so I can log in to my Hotel WiFi.
The message it gives me is:

### Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
**www.google.com** (for example, passwords, messages, or credit
cards)

Answer (score 2):

Open: chrome://flags/

Search flags: #allow-insecure-localhost

Toggle: ***Enabled***

Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost.
Allows requests to localhost over HTTPS even when an invalid certificate is presented. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
***#allow-insecure-localhost***

**Relaunch Chrome**

Forget Problem WIFI Network in Android Saved Networks.

Shut off phone WIFI.

Enable WIFI & connect to network again

Login page should load if not

try going to ask.com it should intercept and redirect you.

[image: WIFI Chrome Fix]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Hotel WiFi [Captive Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) is attempting to impersonate any URLs it sees, which will cause an error if it is an HTTPS connection. This error is there to prevent a [Man-In-The-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) type of attack.

You might need to use a non-HTTPS URL in order to view and accept their Acceptable Use Policy.

Comment: Can you find me a HTTP Protocol link? It's impossible to find one these days...

Comment: http://ipecho.net/ doesn't seem to have HTTPS configured.